# Ant Hoc net simulation on ns2

Tags: simulation, ns2, adhoc

I really hope If someone helps me with this algorithm An Ant-Based Hybrid Routing Algorithm for Mobile Ad Hoc Networks I need to know how to make a simulation with ns2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link. It is a similar project using same kind of routing protocol.

http://www.projectguideline.com/performance-of-swarm-routing-protocol-under-manet/